# javascript regex only numbers with required dots not consecutive

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i create a regex that will accept:

- min 3 numbers
- 3 dots that are not consecutive

For numbers i know that `[0-9]{3,}` would work, but how to add the required 3 dots that are not consecutive?

It can only allow numbers, dots and one /

For example 1.1.1.1/26 or 133.69.1.6 something similar to ip but can allow / as in subnet, but i do not need an exact ip/subnet regex

Comment: Can the string contain things other than numbers and dots?

Comment: can you provide some string which should match and shouldn't match

Comment: @ndn  i have updated my question

Comment: So if you don't need an ip/subnet pattern what are the other possible strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can add lookaheads to achieve extra checks:

- `(?!.*\.\.)` - there are no consecutive dots
- `(?=.*\..*\..*\.)` - there are at least 3 dots
- `(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)` - there are at least 3 digits

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?=.*\..*\..*\.)(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:\/\d+)?$
```

You can use this match `ip` and `subnets`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/2